# Getting PhasescriptExecution Error in Xcode 13.0

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting Error while running Project:

```
file:///Users/AVC/Documents/Simon%20Projects/DemoApp/bin/xcodeproj-checker-config-permissive.yml
ln: /Users/AVC/Documents/Simon Projects/DemoApp/.git/hooks/pre-commit: File exists
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

My XCode Version: 13.0

Swift Vdersion: 4.2

Tried lot of ways But cant find solution.

Comment: You should update Xcode. This might work... I got same issue and It worked on Xcode 13.2.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `.git/hooks/pre-commit`

> That is just a alias and the original file can not be created due to this. script creates new pre-commit file and it's alias at run time.